# Avoid repeats javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, repeat

How I can make the following code shorter to avoid repeats?

```
var condition1 = case1 && case2 && case3 && case4;
var condition2 = case1 && case2 && case3;
```

since case1, 2, 3 are repeats. How I can assign them only once or make it shorter?

thanks

Comment: `var condition2 = case1 && case2 && case3, condition1 = condition2 && case4;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var condition2 = case1 && case2 && case3,
    condition1 = condition2 && case4;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var condition2 = case1 && case2 && case3;
var condition1 = condition2 && case4;
```